# How do I target "label for" with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to empty the HTML of this input and label via jQuery.

```
<input id="inputclass" type="checkbox">

<label for="labelclass">Text</label>
```

For the input it seems to be as simple as doing `$(".inputclass").html("");` with jQuery, but what about for targeting the label?

Comment: Is the code right? The label is not for `inputclass` but for `labelclass` which is not in the code. However, you can target the label by giving it an ID like `inputclass-label`, or targetting it with `$("[for=inputclass]")`

Comment: The `for` attribute value has to be an "id" of some `<input>` element, not  a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery selectors are basically CSS selectors, so:

```
$('label[for="labelclass"]').html('')
```

Also, `<input>` fields don't have an "html" property, so `$('input').html('')` has no effect.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I have to wait 8 mins to accept.

Comment: Make sure the for attribute matches an ID of an input.

Answer (score 1):

First, an `input` can't contain HTML, it has a `value`, so the correct way to clear its value out would be:

```
$("#inputclass").val("");
```

Unless you want to deselect the checkbox, in which case it would be:

```
$("#inputclass").prop("checked", false);
```

A label, on the other hand, may contain nested HTML, so for it you can target the element type and then its `for` attribute value:

```
$("label[for='labelclass']").html("");
```

Comment: Alternative/preferred way to set `checked` property is to use `.prop()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery